# Jenkins and Visual Studio Online integration authentication

Tags: wcf, visual-studio, tfs, jenkins, azure-devops

right now I am trying to Setup Continuouse Integration - Delivery for a basic WCF Service, which will be hosted on a Microsoft Azure VM. The Project is Version Controlled through Visual Studio Online. So I installed Jenkins (also on the Azure VM), TFS plugin etc. and started the first Test Build:

As Server URL I used "[VSO Adress]/DefaultCollection"
and for Login purposes my Microsoft Account (I can Access VSO with that). The Problem is, when I run the Build I get the following error in Jenkins:

> Started by user Developer
>   Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\test\workspace
>   [workspace] $ "C:\Program Files (x86)\TEE-CLC-11.0.0.1306\TEE-CLC-11.0.0\tf.cmd" workspaces -format:brief -server:[VSO Adress]/DefaultCollection ********"
>   An error occurred: Access denied connecting to TFS server [VSO Adress] (authenticating as har****@*******o.com)
>   FATAL: Executable returned an unexpected result code [100]
>   ERROR: null
>   Finished: FAILURE

So my question is, whether it is generally possible to connect Jenkins and VSO that way and if so, which login credentials are needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not be able to authenticate with your Microsoft ID as Jenkins is not able to get the encrypted token. If you head over to VSO you can open your profile (top right) and configure alternative credentials you can use them to login.

Also you can get service account credentials through the API. I created a simple tool for this: http://nakedalm.com/tfs-service-credential-viewer/

It's crude but usually works.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply! I tried the "alternate credentials" Option, but it does not work. Jenkins asks for "username@domain". If i fill in [alternate username]@[VSO Domain], the Failure is the following "Federated authentication to this server requires a username and password." I am unfortunately not able to reach your application to try the second approach

Comment: thank you, now it works with the the alternate credentials. The problem was, that i configured a "secondary user name" in VSO and tried to use it in Jenkins. I dont know why, but this didnt work... After that, I deleted the "secondary User Name". Now I use my Email-Adress (primary User Name) and the pw, which I set in the alternate credential window. This seems to work in Jenkins. Thank You!

Comment: @user3120361 Can you explain what you have tried to do ? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Midhun: For me the following worked to use the Version Control from VSO in Jenkins: In VSO go to your profile on the top right. Then on the top left choose the "security" section. You should then see a Option "Alternate authentication credentials" beneath. There you set an alternate password (but not an secondary user name). Now you should be able to use your primary user name together with the alternate password in Jenkins. I am not sure, but maybe there are better solutions meanwhile